# a branched covering with the critical locus of codimension 2

Tags: complex-geometry

i'm sorry to ask just an exercise of Chapter 4 Section 6 on the book "From Holomorphic Functions to Complex Manifolds" by Grauert and Fritzsche.

Let $f:X\longrightarrow M$ be a branched analytic covering with critical locus $D$ ($D$ is contained in $M$).If $y$ is a point of $D$ such that $D$ has codimension $2$ at $y$, then there is no branch point in the preimage of $y$.

thanks!

Comment: What dimension are X and M?  Do you mean real or complex codimension?

Comment: Do you like this book btw?  It looks great from the table of contents...

Comment: According to the definition of branched coverings,X and M are both n-dimensional complex manifolds,so i mean complex codimention.
i don't like this book,it's difficult to read for me.